# How to get all many to one rows with a specified where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, join, group-by

In a scenario where I have multiple people and every person can have many hobbies, how can I make it so I select the people that have a specified hobby among them but also all other hobbies. If I use a where clauses the query only returns the hobby specified without the others

Like, From all the people show me the people that like to go phishing and also show my all their other hobbies.

I can't explain it to well, [I've made a JsFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/351bb6)

How can I make it so I can see Mike's all other hobbies but make sure one of them is Fighting ?

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(HobbyName) 
FROM people  
    INNER JOIN peoples_hobbies ON pId = peopleId 
    INNER JOIN hobby ON hobbyId = hId 
WHERE HobbyName = 'Fighting' 
GROUP BY name
```

/* if i do this the where clasue makes it so it only selects that hobby, I want to get,
the hobby that i specify and also all the rest that belong to that person ?*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from your existing query, you can just add a `having` clause to filter on persons that have one specific hobby:

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(h.HobbyName) hobbies
FROM people p
INNER JOIN peoples_hobbies ph ON p.pId = ph.peopleId 
INNER JOIN hobby h ON ph.hobbyId = h.Id 
GROUP BY p.pId, p.name
HAVING MAX(h.HobbyName = 'Fighting')
```

Side notes:

- in a multi-table query, *always* qualify each column with the table it belongs to - this make the query much easier to follow, and avoids ambiguity when two different table have a column that has the same name
- `HAVING MAX(h.HobbyName = 'Fighting')` is a MySQL shortcut to say `HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN h.HobbyName = 'Fighting' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1`
- adding the primary key of the `people` table to `group by` clause is safer, as it would properly handle homonyms